# Defining an operation on $\{-1,0,1\}$ so that a group is formed.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

'Determine the properties of an operation $\circ$ in the set $A:=\{-1,0,1\}$, such that $(A,\circ)$ forms a group'.

Let $0$ be the identity element of the group, now $1\circ0=1$, $-1\circ0=-1$,$0\circ0=0$.

If  $(A,\circ)$ forms a group, there must be ( assuming $0$ is the identity element ) one and only one inverse element for each $a\in A$, such that $a \circ a^{-1} = 0$. Now $-1\circ1=0$.

Since the identity and inverse elements must be unique, we can eliminate other results and state that $-1\circ-1=1$ and $1\circ1=-1$. At this point, we can create a table with respect to $\circ$, showing that this is an Abelian group - and therefore a group. What are the flaws in my work? Also, how can I show associativity for $(A,\circ)$, other than proving all possible combinations?

Comment: Almost ok. Only thing missing: Why is $-1 \circ 1 = 0$, so why is $-1$ the inverse of $1$? How can you show that $1 \circ 1 \neq 0 \neq -1 \circ -1$, meaning why aren't all elements self-inverse? Once you have that, the rest seems correct.

Comment: Depending on what you can assume known there is always work to do. One way to save some work is to, instead of defining the operations from scratch, you can pull them back from a known group via a bijective function. For example, $f:A\to\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ sending $f(-1)=0,f(0)=1,f(1)=2$. Then, define $a\circ b=f^{-1}(f(a)f(b))$, for $a,b\in A$. I wouldn't miss the opportunity of making $-1$ the identity instead of $0$ or $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not required to prove there is a unique group of order 3, just that there is one. You know that there is a cyclic group of order 3.

So assuming 0 is the identity element you define $-1\circ-1=1,-1\circ1=0,-1\circ0=-1$, $1\circ1=-1$ and $1\circ0=1$. If you think of $0$ as $(-1)^3$ and $1$ as $(-1)^2$, then it is obvious that the group must be abelian and verification of associativity is trivial.